# What is regular expression for numeric value till 2 decimal places?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am new to regular expression.
I need a regular expression (C#) to match numeric value upto 4 digit before decimal places, and upto 2 digit after decimal places.

Example

It should match the following

```
  1111   
  1211.12  
  1  
  0  
  0.00  
  1.1
```

It should not match following

```
  11.111  
  11111  
  11111.1
```

Comment: Could you tell us why you need to do this? Perhaps there is a better alternative to regex (Or tell us why you want to use regex?)

Comment: I need to read format from config (mapping) file. If input value matches the format, i need to accept, otherwise need to raise error. This is for ~100 fields, and corresponds to 12 such formats.

Comment: 0.0 is permitted, not 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a simple digit quantifier, with a group to test for the decimal portion of the number.

```
^\d{1,4}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

Comment: it should be \d{2} to only match two decimal places.

Comment: The answer is correct. OP wants **up to** two decimal places.

Comment: @Tilak No look-ahead is used in this regex; it is unnecessary to use one. The question mark means "none, or one of".

Comment: It is not as per requirement. It is matching,  11.111, 11111, 11111.1

Comment: @Tilak I tested it in C#, and indeed it did fail for those cases.  The solution was to add start and end delimiters as well.  Updated answer.